# Weird random characters when reading registry with C++

Tags: c++, windows, c++17, registry

So I'm trying to read the registry with C++. However when I do some random ascii characters show up. This only occurs whenever I try to access the SOFTWARE key, it works for any other key.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <windows.h>

//Basic registry tweaking code made by Przemyslaw Zaworski in 2017
//to store passwords

std::string registry_read (LPCTSTR subkey,LPCTSTR name,DWORD type)
{
    HKEY key;
    TCHAR value[255];
    DWORD value_length = 255;
    RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,subkey,&key);
    RegQueryValueEx(key,name, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &value_length);
    RegCloseKey(key);
    return value;
    
}

void registry_write (LPCTSTR subkey,LPCTSTR name,DWORD type,const char* value)
{
    HKEY key;
    RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,subkey,&key);
    RegSetValueEx(key, name, 0, type, (LPBYTE)value, strlen(value)*sizeof(char));
    RegCloseKey(key);
}


int main(){
    //TODO: fix this what the
    std::string text = registry_read("SOFTWARE\\FilePasser","Password",REG_SZ); //Read the registry value
    std::cout << text << std::endl; 
    std::string input;
    return 0;
}
```

*****[This pops up instead of the expected value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDH9W.png)*****

I tried changing to the SOFTWARE to HARDWARE, but it deletes the value on reboot. And the software does this weird bug

Comment: value is NOT a std::string, try `return std::string{value};` But is could also be you need to work with LPCWST and std::wstring

Comment: Most likely, some or all of those `Reg*` calls failed, and `value` still contains uninitialized garbage.

Comment: Add some error checking.  You'll soon find out where your assumptions are breaking down.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation as it stands is different depending on whether you have defined `UNICODE` or not before including `Windows.h` (Check your preprocessor definitions in your project settings). A `TCHAR` is a `WCHAR` in unicode and `CHAR` in ascii. Windows uses utf-16 for its unicode support, in which every character is 16 bits, vs your typical `char` which is 8. So trying to use `std::string` on a utf-16 string is going to cause encoding errors.

If you want unicode, keep the code as is and use `std::wstring` and `std::wcout`. If you don't want unicode, either remove the `UNICODE` definition from your project settings, or replace `TCHAR`s with regular `char`s and use the ascii versions of winapi functions.

Example for non-unicode:

```cpp
std::string registry_read(LPCSTR subkey,LPCSTR name,DWORD type)
{
    HKEY key;
    char value[255];
    DWORD value_length = 255;
    RegOpenKeyA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,subkey,&key);
    RegQueryValueExA(key,name, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &value_length);
    RegCloseKey(key);
    return value;
}
```